# Resteasy JAXRS -Using static final Strings in @ApplicationPath and @Path annotations

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

Is this possible? Let's say there is an interface declaring final static Strings that define application path and paths for resources, so as to have a single reference and ensure consistency in a very large application suite of servers and clients.

The annotations @interface takes a String value. But must this be a string literal?

Anybody tried something like this? Works?

I gave it a quick trial and it appears that it doesn't, why I do not know.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Are you seeing compile errors?

Comment: It compiles fine. It seems as though the implementation of the annotation is not able to resolve an expression into a string result. This seems the likely explanation. The resulting server does not map the resource to the path, resulting in 404 errors.

Comment: By expression do you mean something like `${some.system.property:my-default}`? If so, yes that will not work.

Comment: No public interface RestConstants  { public final static String base="/restapi"; } then @ApplicationPath(RestConstants.base) public class BaseResources blah blah does not work

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. It should compile down to a hard-coded string. If you change it to`@ApplicationPath("/restapi")` does it work?

Comment: hard coded works just fine.

Comment: It definitely seems to work for me on WildFly 25.0.0.Beta1 at least. What version of WildFly are you using? I assume not the Beta :)

Comment: Using 17. So the resteasy implementation must have picked up this function between 17 and 25. Good to know and thanks for checking it out.

Comment: It should really work in any version as that's the byte code would look hard-coded so to speak. I tested on WildFly 17.0.1.Final and it works as well.